# DocuSign REST API: How to track the status as a Carbon Copy recipient?

Tags: java, rest, docusignapi

Carbon copy recipients will receive a copy, after the envelope has been signed. We want to notify these recipients when the status has changed for a certain envelope. Is it possible to track the status of an envelope for a Carbon Copy recipient?

It could be that I should use another type of recipient for this. This user should only have the rights to view the envelope. Which would be the correct one?

Comment: Would it be possible to provide 1-2 explicit examples of what you are looking to accomplish? In short, the CC role is a fire and forget type of event in the workflow. You can customize the contents of the CC email to have it say whatever you want, but if the signer prior to the CC role declines, the workflow ends there and the CC does not get notified (for example)

Comment: Hi Luis, As an example: We are sending emails on behalf of someone. I would like this someone to be informed. This user's mail is the FROM-mail, while the receiving end would be the TO-mail. This FROM-mail should be in the loop for any change that happens, but does not have to have any edit rights. Does this clarify some things for you?

Comment: I have the same question.  We want to have people marked on the envelope that can kind of have some visiblity into the signatures.   Just visibility though, not any ability to change things.

Answer (score 0):

CC Recipients has full visibility into the envelope, they can see the history trail that shows you who signed, when, who just viewed etc. etc.
You can enable certain notifications for the account such that they would be notified about some of the activity, but if you want to provide your own mechanism for notification - you can use connect webHook, get notifications and then decide how to let the CC recipients know about the changes.